# How to change MAC address on startup in Kali Linux

Tags: networking, linux, privacy, kali-linux

I would like Kali Linux to change the MAC addresses of both my network interfaces (eth0 and wlan0) on startup to randomly generated ones. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `macchanger` program which comes preinstalled in kali.

Follow the instructions at [this kali forum](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?36072-SOLVED-Could-not-change-MAC-amp-Setup-Macchanger-auto-spoofing-randomization-in-Kali) to configure it to start at boot.

This [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914278/how-to-randomly-change-the-mac-on-each-boot-in-16-04) discusses how to do it without `macchanger`

Comment: I'd upvote if you also include content (from the links) in your answer. Currently it's just plain references.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't have the time to type it all out but I wanted to provide a quick answer. I did revise the links 3x to provide the best possible ones. And 2 of them have really well documented solutions. No point re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure when you install kali now there will be a pop up window that asks if you want macchanger to do this on boot

Comment: The crap automagic network manager software will make your method unreliable. Either disable this, or change lladdr with networkmanager.

Answer (score 0):

You can program your computer to automatically generate a random MAC address upon reboot by entering the following commands in Terminal:

First, login as root, then enter `crontab -e`.
This will either load a program, or allow you the option to select a program to load it with. (I recommend `nano`.)
Once crontab is loaded, enter a new line at the bottom like this: `@reboot macchanger -r eth0`.
(Make sure it does NOT have a `#` before the line. The pound sign basically tells the program, "ignore this line.")
Then just "Write Out" (save) and exit crontab. Reboot your computer to test it.

You may encounter an issue, like I have, where the randomly generated MAC address does not grant network access.... don't freak out, simply generate a new one with `macchanger -r eth0` until it does. I haven't found a way to avoid that yet... it's annoying, but at least it'll keep you from footprinting your real MAC address somewhere you don't want it.